# PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences crashes app

Tags: android

```
public class User extends Activity implements UserI {   

    private SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    private Context mcontext;
    private boolean isNotificationsOn;


    public User(Context context) {

                mcontext = context;

                Load();
        }

    public void Load () {

       //app crashes 
       sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mcontext);

       isNotificationsOn = sharedPref.getBoolean("switch_recieveNotifications", false);

       }
}


public class SettingsActivity extends 
AppCompatPreferenceActivity {

    ...

    public static class GeneralPreferenceFragment extends 
    PreferenceFragment {

      ...

    }
}
```

Hi everyone,

I'm a new android app developer, and I would really appreciate your help.

My app crashes every time I call: 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).

I have tried different strategies after reading a few answers related, such as:

- passing context as getApplicationContext()
- passing context to the constructor
- creating a GetContext() function in the SettingsActivity which returns its context
- creating a GetContext() function in the static class GeneralPreferenceFragment which returns its context

it all produces the same result- crashing app

I'm lost :/ would love to get your insights

Comment: We need the stacktrace.

Comment: Wait, why does User extend Activity? You can't construct an Activity.

Answer (score 1):

An Activity is the context, it represents the controller for the view.
So your Load should happen either in the onCreate or onResume method.

Then your context should be the keyword "this". You should also consider naming it UserActivity so it is obvious what you are doing. Lastly in Java or Kotlin we start with lowercase method names.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    load()
}
private void load(){
        sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
       isNotificationsOn = sharedPref.getBoolean("switch_recieveNotifications", false); 
}
```

That will get you running again. Then make sure you are starting your activity properly and not trying to build your own constructor. Simply use

```
startActivity(this, new Intent(this, UserActivity));
```